# Native OpenGL ES code runs on emulator but it doesn't run on real device

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es

I'm programming an **OpenGL ES 1.1** app on **Android** (**all OpenGL ES code is C++**).

Testing it on emulator it works fine, but when I test it on a real device (HTC Desire), it doesn't work (I only see a black screen).

This is my OpenGL C++ code:

```
RenderingEngine1::RenderingEngine1()
{
    // Create & bind the color buffer so that the caller can allocate its space.
    glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &m_renderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, m_renderbuffer);
}

void RenderingEngine1::Initialize(int width, int height)
{
    // Create the framebuffer object and attach the color buffer.
    glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &m_framebuffer);
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, m_framebuffer);
    glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES,
                                 GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES,
                                 GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES,
                                 m_renderbuffer);

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    // Initialize the projection matrix.
    const float maxX = 2;
    const float maxY = 3;
    glOrthof(-maxX, +maxX, -maxY, +maxY, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    // Initialize the rotation animation state.
    OnRotate(DeviceOrientationPortrait);
    m_currentAngle = m_desiredAngle;
}

void RenderingEngine1::Render() const
{
    glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(m_currentAngle, 0, 0, 1);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), &Vertices[0].Position[0]);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), &Vertices[0].Color[0]);

    GLsizei vertexCount = sizeof(Vertices) / sizeof(Vertex);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

JNI methods are in this C++ code:

```
extern "C" {
    IRenderingEngine* m_renderingEngine;

    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved)
    {
        return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
    }

    void Java_com_company_tests_MainRenderer_nativeInit( JNIEnv*  env, jobject thiz )
    {
        m_renderingEngine = CreateRenderer1();
        m_renderingEngine->Initialize(480, 800);
    }

    void Java_com_company_tests_MainRenderer_nativeRender( JNIEnv*  env, jobject thiz )
    {
        m_renderingEngine->Render();
    }
}
```

And I also have two Java classes: one that inherits from **GLSurfaceView**, and a renderer that implements **GLSurfaceView.Renderer**.

I don't know why it doesn't work on a real device.

Any advice?

If you need something else, please tell me.

Comment: Did you find the cause?

Comment: No, sorry. Do you have the same problem?

Comment: When I wrote the comment above, I was searching for causes of the AVD rendering OGL2 "correctly" while on devices, the screen would be just black. I have now identified the problem by systematically reducing my test case. In my case, it was my fragment shader's fault. The AVD's shader compiler will happily accept mixed floating point and fixed point arithmetics/notations, such as "float1 / 2", but my two devices' won't. They need "float1 / 2.0" to be happy.